# size of a set in Maple

Tags: maple

Sorry for my dumb question, but
how can I get the size of a set (the max index number)?

Is there a built in function, or i have to count it in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you're looking for is nops.

That's short for "number of operands", and it also works for lists.